# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Rf7.png)
Hey There,

- I'm trying to find the answer in which continent has the maximum Data Rate.
  `max_data_rate_continent = df.groupby(['Data.Rate']).max()['Location.Continent']`

  So, it gives me error like this
  `ValueError:  wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
max_data_rate_continent = df.loc[df['Data.Rate'].idxmax(), 'Location.Continent']
```